# How to fix my spacing issue when writing to .txt file?

Tags: vba, text, excel, excel-2007, spacing

I have created an Excel Workbook with a macro designed to export all data from a worksheet to a fixed-width .txt file.

I've got everything working perfectly except for one thing. My XWGHT field comes across with spaces after the field values, when they need to be before. Below I have attached what I am looking at. The upper window is a file containing real example data, the below my test data written to .txt file.

Unsure if the additional information will help, but my worksheet that is being exported to text has all fields formatted as "Text"

[image: FileComparisons]

My Code:

```
'Export
Sub Export()

    'Clear out Export Worksheet
    Worksheets("Export").Cells.ClearContents

    ' Fill "Export" worksheet with the desired columns from "FeedSamples" in the order
    ' listed in ImpfileFDF.pdf found in \\agfiles\public\Formflow

    ' Use rowCnt to designate the range to copy to "Export" worksheet
    Dim rowCnt As Long
    rowCnt = Worksheets("FeedSamples").range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

    ' LABELRENO = XLABLER
    Worksheets("Export").range("A1:A" & rowCnt).value = Worksheets("FeedSamples").range("A1:A" & rowCnt).value
    ' XRPTNO = REPTNO
    Worksheets("Export").range("B1:B" & rowCnt).value = Worksheets("FeedSamples").range("B1:B" & rowCnt).value
    ' XPROD = B
    Worksheets("Export").range("C1:C" & rowCnt).value = Worksheets("FeedSamples").range("C1:C" & rowCnt).value
    ' XCLS1 = PRODNO1
    Worksheets("Export").range("D1:D" & rowCnt).value = Worksheets("FeedSamples").range("E1:E" & rowCnt).value
    ' XCLS2 = PRODNO2
    Worksheets("Export").range("E1:E" & rowCnt).value = Worksheets("FeedSamples").range("F1:F" & rowCnt).value
    ' XCLS3 = PRODNO3
    Worksheets("Export").range("F1:F" & rowCnt).value = Worksheets("FeedSamples").range("G1:G" & rowCnt).value
    ' DESC1 = XDSC1
    Worksheets("Export").range("G1:G" & rowCnt).value = Worksheets("FeedSamples").range("H1:H" & rowCnt).value
    ' DESC2 = XDSC2
    Worksheets("Export").range("H1:H" & rowCnt).value = Worksheets("FeedSamples").range("I1:I" & rowCnt).value
    ' DESC3 = XDSC3
    Worksheets("Export").range("I1:I" & rowCnt).value = Worksheets("FeedSamples").range("J1:J" & rowCnt).value
    ' DESC4 = XDSC4
Worksheets("Export").range("J1:J" & rowCnt).value = Worksheets("FeedSamples").range("K1:K" & rowCnt).value
    ' POSSNO = XPOSSR
    Worksheets("Export").range("K1:K" & rowCnt).value = Worksheets("FeedSamples").range("L1:L" & rowCnt).value
    ' DATEINSP = XDATE
    Worksheets("Export").range("L1:L" & rowCnt).value = Worksheets("FeedSamples").range("M1:M" & rowCnt).value
    ' SAMRECNO = XRCPT#
    Worksheets("Export").range("M1:M" & rowCnt).value = Worksheets("FeedSamples").range("N1:N" & rowCnt).value
    ' NOBAGS = XNOBAG
    Worksheets("Export").range("N1:N" & rowCnt).value =     Worksheets("FeedSamples").range("O1:O" & rowCnt).value
    ' NOGUAR = XNOGAR
    Worksheets("Export").range("O1:O" & rowCnt).value = Worksheets("FeedSamples").range("P1:P" & rowCnt).value
    ' ANALYSIS49 = X49
    Worksheets("Export").range("P1:P" & rowCnt).value = Worksheets("FeedSamples").range("S1:S" & rowCnt).value
    ' ANALYSIS50 = X50
    Worksheets("Export").range("Q1:Q" & rowCnt).value = Worksheets("FeedSamples").range("T1:T" & rowCnt).value
    ' BAGTAG = XMRKCD
    Worksheets("Export").range("R1:R" & rowCnt).value = Worksheets("FeedSamples").range("U1:U" & rowCnt).value
    ' ONHAND = XONHND
    Worksheets("Export").range("S1:S" & rowCnt).value = Worksheets("FeedSamples").range("V1:V" & rowCnt).value
    ' WTLBS = XWGHT
    Worksheets("Export").range("T1:T" & rowCnt).value = Worksheets("FeedSamples").range("W1:W" & rowCnt).value
    ' REMARKS = XCOMNT
    Worksheets("Export").range("U1:U" & rowCnt).value = Worksheets("FeedSamples").range("AA1:AA" & rowCnt).value
    ' MED = XMED
    Worksheets("Export").range("V1:V" & rowCnt).value = Worksheets("FeedSamples").range("AK1:AK" & rowCnt).value
    ' NONMED = XNOMED
    Worksheets("Export").range("W1:W" & rowCnt).value = Worksheets("FeedSamples").range("AL1:AL" & rowCnt).value
    ' GUARANL = XGANAL
    Worksheets("Export").range("X1:X" & rowCnt).value = Worksheets("FeedSamples").range("BP1:BP" & rowCnt).value
    ' GUARANMENT = XGMET
    Worksheets("Export").range("Y1:Y" & rowCnt).value = Worksheets("FeedSamples").range("BQ1:BQ" & rowCnt).value
    ' FLAGSAM = XFLAG
    Worksheets("Export").range("Z1:Z" & rowCnt).value = Worksheets("FeedSamples").range("Q1:Q" & rowCnt).value
    ' SAMDEF = XTYPE
    Worksheets("Export").range("AA1:AA" & rowCnt).value = Worksheets("FeedSamples").range("R1:R" & rowCnt).value
    ' TAKENOTHER = XTAKEN
    Worksheets("Export").range("AB1:AB" & rowCnt).value = Worksheets("FeedSamples").range("AS1:AS" & rowCnt).value
    ' METH1 = XMETHD
    Worksheets("Export").range("AC1:AC" & rowCnt).value = Worksheets("FeedSamples").range("AT1:AT" & rowCnt).value

    ' Need to format date fields from MM/DD/YYYY to MMDDYYYY for insertion to .txt file
    Dim n As Integer
    For n = 2 To rowCnt
        Worksheets("Export").range("L" & n).value = Format(Worksheets("Export").range("L" & n).value, "mmddyyyy")
    Next

    Dim txtFile As String
    txtFile = "\\filePATH\Personal Project Notes\IMPFILE.txt"
    'Specify the widths of fields
    'The number of columns is the number specified in the line below +1
    Dim s(29) As Integer
    s(0) = 6
    s(1) = 6
    s(2) = 4
    s(3) = 1
    s(4) = 2
    s(5) = 1
    s(6) = 1
    s(7) = 1
    s(8) = 1
    s(9) = 1
    s(10) = 6
    s(11) = 8
    s(12) = 6
    s(13) = 2
    s(14) = 2
    s(15) = 1
    s(16) = 1
    s(17) = 40
    s(18) = 12
    s(19) = 6
    s(20) = 79
    s(21) = 1
    s(22) = 1
    s(23) = 2
    s(24) = 2
    s(25) = 1
    s(26) = 1
    s(27) = 17
    s(28) = 18

    'Write data to file
    CreateFixedWidthFile txtFile, Worksheets("Export"), s

End Sub

Sub CreateFixedWidthFile(strFile As String, ws As Worksheet, s() As Integer)
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim strLine As String, strCell As String

    'Get Freefile
    Dim fNum As Long
    fNum = FreeFile

    ' Open Textfile
    Open strFile For Output As fNum

    ' Loop through all rows. i = 1 to include Headers in txt file, 2 to ignore Header row
    For i = 2 To ws.range("a65536").End(xlUp).row
        ' New Line
        strLine = ""
        ' Loop through each cell (field) in row
        For j = 0 To UBound(s)
            ' Write only to the length of the field
            strCell = Left$(ws.Cells(i, j + 1).value, s(j))
            ' Add spaces to field value if value less than field length maximum
        strLine = strLine & strCell & String$(s(j) - Len(strCell), Chr$(32))
        Next j
        ' Write record to file
        Print #fNum, strLine
    Next i
    ' Close file
    Close #fNum

End Sub
```

**EDIT:**

[image: SUCCESS!]

Thanks so much Tim! Sorry I goofed yesterday and didn't notice the comment you placed in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT** (after reading the question more carefully)

```
For j = 0 To UBound(s)
    tmp = ws.Cells(i, j + 1).value
    pad = String(s(j),Chr(32))   
    If j = 10 Then 'change number to required column
        strLine = strLine & Right(pad & tmp, s(j))  'pad on left
    else
        strLine = strLine & Left(tmp & pad, s(j))  'pad on right
    end if   
Next j
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Tim. I tried replacing my 2 lines of code in my For "j" loop with your line of code above, but sadly, still getting the same result :/

Comment: Are you sure your original data doesn't already have some padding?

Comment: Positive. Everything in the workbook is stored as "Text", no other formatting or alignment settings. My code sets the column widths, and adds in the spaces as needed to fully fill out the fixed-widths of the column when values do not meet the max length.

Comment: As my comment above in the other answer: ignoring formatting aspects of the data, are you confident that none of the **source values** include any spaces? That's the only thing which might account for what you're seeing in the screenshot you posted.

Comment: I'm positive. If you look at my code, **I** am putting the spaces in to fit the values to the full max length of the field. I need a way to, for this one field value, set the spaces before the value, not after.

Comment: My Apologies: I totally mis-read your question!  See my edit.

Comment: I tried your edit, but sadly I am getting the exact same result... :/

Comment: OK - I think we're stuck without being able to see your actual data.

Comment: Tim, I offer you my sincerest thanks, and apologies! I was worn down at the end of yesterday and had not even noticed your comment about changing 'j = 10' to the appropriate column. Made the change this morning, and as you can see in the EDIT of my initial post, everything is now lining up as it should be, spaces and all! Thanks so much!

Comment: Glad to hear you figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

From the snapshot, I am under the impression that it is an alignment problem. The spreadsheet might have different alignments for different cells and the code you wrote do not take care of this issue. Try this after each writing line:
Worksheets("Export").range("" & rowCnt).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter

Comment: Thanks for the reply Alvaro. I will look into it more and get back to you. I suspected that may be the issue earlier and can confirm all cells in my worksheet are "Text" with no alignment at all besides "Bottom Align".

Comment: Analytic Lunatic -> You are welcome. Good luck.     Tim Williams -> It is not intended to change the value property, it is intended to change the alignment property. If he writes the provided line after each line modifying the value property, the resulting cell will have the given alignment (not the default one).

Comment: Cell formatted alignment in the worksheet does not appear to be affecting anything one way or another. In my code above I'm adding the spaces in after the field value is written if the field value is not the max length of the fixed width column. For this one single field I need to add the spaces before the value when it is written and not the max length of the fixed width column.

Comment: OK. I thought that it was alignment because this thing of having a bunch of cells left-aligned and another bunch right-aligned has happened to me quite a few times; that's why I always include the alignment I want together with the value and thought that was your problem too. By looking at the picture I do continue seeing an alignment or a blank-spaces issue (easily solved with a simple "trim") rather than other thing, but well... I guess that it is just a visual effect :)

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm following you? Everything in the workbook is stored as "Text", no other formatting or alignment settings. My code sets the column widths, and adds in the spaces as needed to fully fill out the fixed-widths of the column when values do not meet the max length. Trim will be of no help, as I need the spaces, not get rid of them.

Comment: Have you tried trimming the values *before* padding them to the required length? I think this is what @varocarbas is suggesting. The cell format, alignment or column widths won't affect any previously-existing extra spaces

Comment: @AnalyticLunatic sorry about not having understood the problem properly. I think that I know where the problem is: "adds in the spaces as needed"; if I understand this sentence correctly, what you are doing is adding extra blank spaces to make sure that all the values, independently on their length, will be aligned. You don't need to add any extra space, Excel takes care of this with the alignments (all the cells have format; if you don't set any format, they take the default one). If you remove the blank spaces and include the alignments as suggested, everything should be fine.

Comment: @TimWilliams yes, this is what I meant but, apparently, the problem is not there.

Comment: Still a little off there varocarbas... Excel is taking my data and inserting to a .txt file. This file is used to insert the data into a AS400 system. For the insert to work, the data must be in an exact format. Each field has a set amount of characters that can be accepted (thus the fixed-width values of my columns in the .txt file). The spaces are NEEDED. The issue is my one field has spaces on the right (as coded) but needs to have the spaces to the left of the field value. For whatever reason, this ONE field needs the spaces to the right, not left. Only this ONE field needs this change.

Comment: @AnalyticLunatic sorry about not having understood a so evident fact from a so clear picture and so detailed indications. Next time, try to start with this paragraph and perhaphs (ONLY PERHAPS) will get your solution sooner. XWGHT is apparently the wrong field but if I search for this string I only find a comment (' WTLBS = XWGHT) could you please tell me where in your code is this field being written such that I can understand what might be wrong, PLEASE?

Comment: @AnalyticLunatic if this line refers to the problematic cell "Worksheets("Export").range("T1:T" & rowCnt).value = Worksheets("FeedSamples").range("W1:W" & rowCnt).value" I would still have various unknown facts like what values are written in the referred ranges. If all the values are right except one I would do two things in your position (I don't have the data): 1. check that the given input is OK. 2. Execute the macro from the code and see what happens when the given cell is being processed (you should focus just on the part where the extra REQUIRED blank spaces are being added).

Comment: The section of code where that comment is moves the needed columns (there is more data collected than needing output) of data from one worksheet to another for Export to .txt file. 'CreateFixedWidthFile()' is where the data on this other worksheet is written to the .txt file. 's(19)' is the column in question where the spacing needs to be on the left, not the right when output to the .txt file.

Comment: The needed spaces to fill the fixed-width columns are inserted inside my inner-most For loop near the end of my code.

Comment: @AnalyticLunatic much clearer now, thanks. I can only come with the two reasons above: either the input values are wrong (already some blank spaces in the source) or a step-by-step execution should be done (or check the blank-spaces-assignation formula for the given input conditions and confirm that outputs the right value). From this position is impossible to tell what is wrong. Analyse the specific situation or provide the data (spreadsheet).

Comment: @AnalyticLunatic just to clarify: I didn't read the whole code. I am new on all this online programming advising, but I guess that a big proportion of people thinks like me: if the problem is evident (or apparently evident, like in this case), going through a not-so-small code is not the first thing coming to my mind. Thus, to avoid future problems, next time be a bit more concise. In any case, I accept my responsability on the misunderstanding and on having kept proposing things without making sure that I did understand the conditions properly. Sorry for the inconveniences.

Comment: There are no blank spaces in the source. Any spaces are added by my code. It's not that the spaces are occurring in the wrong spot, they need to be coded differently for the ONE field. I appreciate you trying to help, but when advising online, especially code, I'd recommend reading the whole thing (especially if there are comments). I believe the problem was about as straight-forward as could be, but you were making logical conclusions when reading to assume what the problem was. Thanks all the same, I do appreciate you trying.

Comment: ' Add spaces to field value if value less than field length maximum
        strLine = strLine & strCell & String$(s(j) - Len(strCell), Chr$(32))    -> this is the part of the code in charge of adding the blank spaces in your code. Just to make things clear: this problem has, most likely, a 1-min solution. But you are not providing the information. For example, to know if this function works or not I would need to know the input value for the wrong cells you are intending to fix and the expected output. You should appreciate my patience, more than my trying; I haven't tried anything.

Comment: PS: I have been way too polite and nice; because I am new on this and because I do this by default with everyone; but there is people clearly not deserving being treated politely. Please, continue your search of the impossible, 1-min-solvable problem but don't count with my help.

Comment: Ok. I guess that I do have to re-apologise (the algorithm was wrong; even though it was working for most of the cases); but by letting very clear that the whole situation would have been much quicker with better information and with a different attitude. I haven't liked your attitude at all and I don't apologise for that.

Comment: No doubt, clearer explanations could be had. Live and learn. In either case, feelings are mutual, have a good day :)